# jquery Treeview highlighting selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

i read docs

> http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview/treeview#options

also googled, but nothing found easy and good solution, how to highlighting the selected item. i use span so not redirect but nothing selected

Comment: What do you mean by the selected item? The item that was last clicked on? I would personally recommend jstree as a jQuery plugin to handle trees like that since it has a larger and more extensive API structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select li items in the tree and add event listeners to them, like this:

```
$('#browser li.file').bind('click', function() {
  //clear all clicked items if any
  $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
  //set this clicked
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
})
```

Inside handler function 'this' word points to the clicked item.
Or if by 'selecting' you mean something else, you can also listen desired event type like in example.

```
$('#browser li.file').bind('mouseover', function() {
 ... your code ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will work for highlighting the file in a treeview:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#index").treeview();
          $('#index span.file').bind('click', function() {
              //clear all clicked items if any
              $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
              //set this clicked
              $(this).addClass('selected');
            });
      });
```

In `jquery.treeview.css`:

```
.treeview span.file.selected { background-color: #F0FFF0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the tree view, add an id tag to the added branches.

```
"<li><span id="myNode1" class='file'>Item2</span></li>"
```

Then you can use jQuery highlight to highlight the selected node.

```
$("#myNode1").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Or permanently change the style

```
$('#myNode1').css('styleFloat');
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be out of date but I got past it by adding the following under jqueryFileTree.js's FileTree function (version 2.14)

```
function FileTree(el, args, callback) {
  ...
  $el.delegate("li a", this.options.folderEvent, _this.onEvent);
  $el.delegate("li a", "click", function(event){
    $("#" + $el[0].id + " li a.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
}
```